# How do I get the return type of a class method in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

In newer TypeScript versions (I think 2.8 onwards?), I can easily obtain the return type of a function:

```
function f() { return "hi"; }
type MyType = ReturnType<typeof f>; //MyType is string
```

But I can't figure out to get the same info from a class method…

```
class MyClass {
  foo() { return "hi"; }
}
```

How do I get the return type of `(new MyClass()).foo()` ?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

To get property or method type, you can use [indexed access type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types):

```
type FooReturnType = ReturnType<MyClass['foo']>;
```

Comment: I've been searching for hours! Thank you!