# how to write a generic function that calls a method of an object

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

There are two class:

```js
class STRING_TYPE {
    name():string{
        return "one";
    }
}
class NUMBER_TYPE {
    name():number{
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I want to write a generic function:

1. create an object of the given class
2. call name() method, and return its value;
   In javascript, code like:

```js
function foo(classType) {
    const obj = new classType();
    return obj.name();
}
```

How to write it in typescript?

```js
// it doesn't work.
function foo<T>(typ: T): ReturnType<T.name>{
    const obj = new T();
    return obj.name();
}
```

Comment: Your JS version will also not work. There is no `name` method in `STRING_TYPE`.

Comment: It was my mistake, I just fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a constraint for `classType` argument:

```js
class STRING_TYPE {
  value(): string {
    return "one";
  }
}
class NUMBER_TYPE {
  name(): number {
    return 1;
  }
}

type AnyClass<Return> = new (...args: any[]) => Return

const foo = <Klass extends AnyClass<{ name: () => number }>>(classType: Klass) =>
  new classType().name();
  
const result = foo(NUMBER_TYPE)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKAqAlAkgOQOIH14E0AKAotAN4BQ00AbmCAK4CmAFAJQBc0EALgE4CWAdgHMS5CtG71Otbv2gAiAPb96cgNyiAvqS2hIMVAFUAsgCECibPiJkK-MAFsmbaP1r2ARvW4ix4ydNkARnUKLS1STgBPAAd6aABBfkiAYXAoAB5EfxkAPmgAXhd6AHdoRgA6SrBuQQh2MCSAbQBdZgK8rKkZUlJgJS5oADMFBQLodIBpNJh6AA9Oen4AExhElOn04hcHenYWdpc3T28NHJzGXSh4GN3oKb02-JzRZVLLiGvYlnK7RxYQ6C9fqcPwQWggEGFYYKRiGUzmSyEZhAA)

`foo` expects a class constructor with `name` method. TS is able to infer return type.

**UPDATE**

```js
class STRING_TYPE {
  name(): string {
    return "one";
  }
}
class NUMBER_TYPE {
  name(): number {
    return 1;
  }
}

type AnyClass<R> = new (...args: any[]) => R

const foo = <
  Return extends { name: () => any },
  Klass extends AnyClass<Return>,
  >(classType: Klass): ReturnType<InstanceType<Klass>['name']> =>
  new classType().name()

foo(NUMBER_TYPE) // number
foo(STRING_TYPE) // string
```

Comment: sorry, there was a mistake in the first version of the question: the `vaue():string` method of `STRING_TYPE` should be `name():string`. maybe can use `ReturnType<InstanceType<Klass>['name']` as the return type?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class STRING_TYPE {
  value(): string {
    return 'one';
  }
}

class NUMBER_TYPE {
  name(): number {
    return 1;
  }
}

function foo(classType: typeof STRING_TYPE): string; // ReturnType<STRING_TYPE['value']>
function foo(classType: typeof NUMBER_TYPE): number; // ReturnType<NUMBER_TYPE['name']>

function foo(classType: typeof STRING_TYPE | typeof NUMBER_TYPE) {
  const obj = new classType();
  return obj instanceof STRING_TYPE ? obj.value() : obj.name();
}

const bar = foo(STRING_TYPE);
const baz = foo(NUMBER_TYPE);
console.log(bar, baz);
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wv80MN)

---

Assuming you did a typo while asking question here, and both your classes have a `name` method, you can do this:

```
class STRING_TYPE {
  name(): string {
    return 'one';
  }
}

class NUMBER_TYPE {
  name(): number {
    return 1;
  }
}

type ClassType =
  | typeof STRING_TYPE
  | typeof NUMBER_TYPE;

function foo<T extends ClassType>(classType: T) {
  const obj = new classType();
  return obj.name() as ReturnType<InstanceType<T>['name']>;
}

const bar = foo(STRING_TYPE);
const baz = foo(NUMBER_TYPE);
console.log(bar, baz);
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wy5dgW)

---

References:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/12802317#comment31618674_12871488
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48808100
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/53289298